# Is there anyway to access this textblock?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, listbox, parameter-passing, textblock

I want to access the text content after binding of the "GameName" textblock that is inside the listbox.

```
        <controls:PanoramaItem Header="games" Margin="0" Height="800" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <!--Double line list with text wrapping-->
            <ListBox x:Name="GamesListBox" Margin="0,0,-12,66"  Height="614" ItemsSource="{Binding dataFeed}" SelectionChanged="GamesListBox_SelectionChanged">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,17">
                            <!--Replace rectangle with image-->
                            <Image Height="100" Width="100"  Source="{Binding AllGamesImage}" Margin="12,0,9,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
                            <StackPanel Width="311">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="GameName" Text="{Binding AllGamesTitle}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="White" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" Margin="0,0,0,1"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding AllGamesDescription}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </controls:PanoramaItem>
```

i want to take whatever is set as the text content and pass it to another page as a parameter or anything.

code behind after Shawn Kendrot suggestion.

```
    private void GamesListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var myObject = GamesListBox.SelectedItem as NewGamesClass;
        string gameName = myObject.TitleCode;

        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Pages/AchivementListPage.xaml?gameName=" + gameName, UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

i get a NullExeception when returing to the page here:

string gameName = myObject.TitleCode;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why access the Text property when you can access the property of the object?

```
void GamesListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var myObject = GamesListBox.SelectedItem as MyObject;
    string gameName = myObject.AllGamesTitle;
    // Do something with gameName
}
```

Comment: Yup, embrace the power of binding. Controls are meant to just display, and capture for their bound object. Go to the object, the source of Truth.

Comment: this worked, but now when i return to the page i get a NullReferenceException.

Comment: Fixed by placing the webclient method into the contructor, instead of the papplication page loaded. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ListBoxItem selItem = (ListBoxItem)(listboxWeight.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(listboxWeight.SelectedIndex));

StackPanel weightpanel = (StackPanel)selItem.Content;

var child1 = weightpanel.Children[0] as TextBlock;
var child2 = weightpanel.Children[1] as TextBlock;
```